# margin-right not working on image

Tags: html, css, css-animations, margin

I have been trying to use `margin-right` in my CSS animation on an image. The other one working with `margin-left` is working fine. Both `width:100%` and `display:block` at `container` is producing the same results. Have tried with nesting both of them in individual `div`'s also, but not working. It probably has something to do with HTML element placing in the DOM, but I currently have no idea what might be causing it.

Both the images should slide to the opposite directions and open like a door.

This is the code :

```css
#container {
    width: block;
    height: 100vh;
}

#door-left {
    margin-top: -3vh; 
   position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    -webkit-animation: left 4s ease 1 forwards;
    -moz-animation: left 4s ease 1 forwards;
    -o-animation: left 4s ease 1 forwards;
    animation: left 4s ease 1 forwards;
 
}

#door-right {  
    margin-top: -3vh; 
   position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    -webkit-animation: right 4s ease 1 forwards;
    -moz-animation: right 4s ease 1 forwards;
    -o-animation: right 4s ease 1 forwards;
    animation: right 4s ease 1 forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes left {
    from {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: -80vw;
    }
 } 

@-moz-keyframes left {
    from {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: -80vw;
    }
 } 

 @-o-keyframes left {
    from {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: -80vw;
    }
 }

@keyframes left {
   from {
       margin-left: 0;
   }
   to {
       margin-left: -80vw;
   }
}

@-webkit-keyframes right {
    from {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    to {
        margin-right: -80vw;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes right {
    from {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    to {
        margin-right: -80vw;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes right {
    from {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    to {
        margin-right: -80vw;
    }
}

@keyframes right {
    from {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    to {
        margin-right: -80vw;
    }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Q6OvLlG.jpg" id="door-left"/><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ysAVVGd.jpg" id="door-right"/>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Not working in both Chrome and Firefox. So not probably a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is logical, because if you set a negative `margin-left` to the first image you will pull it and **ALL the content after it** (including the second image) to the left.

By setting a negative `margin-right` to the second image you will not have the effect you expect, it will also pull **ALL the content after to overlap** the image.

Here is an example so you can better see what is happening:

```css
.block {
  padding:0 50px;
  font-size:0;
}
.block > div {
  display:inline-block;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
.left {
  border:1px solid blue;
}
.right {
  border:1px solid orange;
}
.after {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
before margin
<div class="block">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>
after margin
<div class="block">
  <div class="left" style="margin-left:-50px"></div>
  <div class="right" style="margin-right:-50px"></div>
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>
```

In your case better consider left and right properties and you will have exactly what needed:

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

#container {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#door-left {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  animation: left 4s ease 1 forwards;
}

#door-right {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  animation: right 4s ease 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes left {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: -80vw;
  }
}

@keyframes right {
  from {
    right: 0;
  }
  to {
    right: -80vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Q6OvLlG.jpg" id="door-left">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ysAVVGd.jpg" id="door-right">
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly as intended. Also the description was clear enough. Thanks!